# SharePoint 2010 Email notification is not sent when adding to the user any SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-server

When user is added to any new or existing SharePoint group, email notification is not being sent to the user. But the user is added successfully to the group. Also if the user is granted permission directly then they get email notification.

Any suggestion will be helpful. I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following article:

[SharePoint Alert Notifications Not Working - Checklist for Troubleshooting](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-troubleshooting-checklist.html)

[SharePoint Troubleshooting: Alert Email Does Not Go Out](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.sharepoint-troubleshooting-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx)

Additionally, you may also try SharePoint auditing [solution](https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/sharepoint-auditing.html) which assists to track the critical changes and get instant alerts via  email notification to recipient with granular level report.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Looked into all of it and still not resolved the issue. Interestingly, if i grant user permission first directly and then add the user to the group then email notification is sent. But if the user is added to the group first without any permission level assigned to him, then email notification is not sent.